# D3.js radar chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, tooltip

Based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/21746a9668ffdf6d8242) example of a D3.js radar chart, I'm trying to have a more advanced type of tooltips. Instead of just a number, I want to show a list of names and numbers, some of them based on my dataset.

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
blobCircleWrapper.selectAll(".radarInvisibleCircle")
                        .data(function(d,i) { return d; })
                        .enter().append("circle")
                        .attr("class", "radarInvisibleCircle")
                        .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius*1.5)
                        .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                        .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice*i - Math.PI/2); })
                        .style("fill", "none")
                        .style("pointer-events", "all")
                        .on("click", function(d,i) {   // TOOLTIP WITH SUBJECTS AND AVERAGES HERE
                            newX =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
                            newY =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 10;

                            tooltip
                                .attr('x', newX)
                                .attr('y', newY)
                                .html(d.value+ "<br>" + "To:")
                                .transition().duration(200)
                                .style('opacity', 1);
                        })
                        .on("mouseout", function(){
                            tooltip.transition().duration(200)
                                .style("opacity", 0);
                        });


                    //Set up the small tooltip for when you hover over a circle
                    var tooltip = g.append("text")
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")
                        .style("opacity", 0);
```

The tooltip is set for the circles of the radar, and when I try to create a `div` element instead of the `text`element, the tooltip stops showing, although the element is created and well positioned. I was trying something like this:

```
var tooltip = g.append("div")
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")
                        .style("opacity", 0);
```

I'm sure I'm missing some attributes here, but is there a way to have more complete tooltips? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `<div>` as tooltip. Thus, you have some different rules here.

First, you cannot append a div to a SVG (I suppose that the `g` selection in your snippet is a SVG group). You'll have to append the div to the body (or any other HTML element).

Second, as you're appending the div to the HTML, you cannot set the `x` and `y` positions as attributes. Instead of that, you'll have to use [event.pageX](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event) and [event.pageY](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event), with an `absolute` position for the div.

Here is a very simple demo with the basics os what I just said:

```js
var tip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("foo")
    .data(d3.range(7))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => 20 + d * 40)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("r", 15)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .on("mousemove", (d, i) => {
        tip.html("This is the<br>circle number " + i)
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
            .style("opacity", 1)
    }).on("mouseout", () => {
        tip.style("opacity", 0)
    })
```

```css
.tip{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I always tend to confuse myself when creating these kinds of tooltips. I always append the `div` elements to the SVG and not to the body. I won't forget it now. Thank you. On a side note, do you think these are the best type of tooltips?

Comment: @Shoplifter.Doe Well, "best type" is something opinion-based... All I can say is that these are the tooltips I use in my codes.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm welcome to take your opinion, since you're a skilled D3.js user and contributor here. Thank you :)